# What's the space between paragraphs?

Tags: spacing, sectioning

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{First paragraph} \lipsum[4]
\paragraph{Second paragraph} \lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

What is, and what sets, the space between these two paragraphs? I've looked in both `article.cls` and `size10.clo`, but I'm not able to find anything.

Comment: The name `\paragraph` is a very unfortunate choice. Are you sure you're not misusing it? What really is your aim?

Comment: note that `\paragraph` is a 4th level section heading so should be used in sequence with \section,\subsection,\subsubsection,\paragraph

Comment: @egreg Oh, I'm definitely misusing it. I had to write an academic abstract in a hurry and just didn't have time to define my own sections with `titlesec`, so I used the predefined `\paragraph` because it came close to what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following macro definition is in `article.cls`:

```
\newcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
```

The `\@startsection` macro takes six arguments; the fourth specifies the amount of vertical whitespace that should be inserted *above* sectioning headers. For sectioning headers of type `paragraph`, the default amount of vertical whitespace is a "rubber" length" (a TeX jargon expression...) of `3.25ex plus 1ex minus 0.2ex`. The whitespace is *not* inserted if the sectioning command occurs at the very top of a page.

The fifth argument of `\@startsection`, if positive, specifies the amount of whitespace to be inserted *below* the sectioning header; if negative, it specifies the offset of a run-in style header.

Comment: Why does it say `3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex` instead of `4.05ex`?

Comment: @Sverre it's a rubber length, those are how much it can stretch. It's 3.25 ex under normal circumstances and it can stretch as high as 4.25 ex and as low as 3.05 ex, but 3.25 ex is where it is ordinarily

Comment: @Sverre - `\@plus` and `\@minus` are (probably unsurprisingly) internal representations of `plus` and `minus`. A length of `4.05ex` is a *fixed* or *rigid* length. In contrast, `3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex` can be as long as `4.25ex` and as short as `3.05ex`, with a default value of `3.25ex`. Having a bit of vertical whitespace to "play with" is important for creating a good-looking page out of sectioning headers and text blocks.

Answer (score 2):

It is the `\paragraph` heading. You can use `titlesec` and its `\titlespacing` to remove it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0pt}{0pt}{1em}
%                          |    |    |
%                 indent --+    |    |
%                 skip before --+    |
%     sep between heading and text --+

\begin{document}
\paragraph{First paragraph} \lipsum[4]
\paragraph{Second paragraph} \lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

---

With KOMA-Script classes one would use `\RedeclareSectionCommand`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt]{paragraph}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{First paragraph} \lipsum[4]
\paragraph{Second paragraph} \lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I know I can choose my own settings with `titlesec`, but in this case I want to know what the spacing is, not how to change it.